# Looking for combination of temperature sensor and thermostat - any hints?

Tags: thermostat, temperature, battery

After reading a lot, I am still very confused... Maybe you could give me some hint?

I am looking for:

1. a temperature sensor in my room
2. a thermostat on my radiator

It is important to me that these are separate devices, because the drop of temperature across the room maybe large and I want to control the temperature of the place where the sensor is.

The temperature sensor shall control my thermostat. The system should be programmable. If possible, both systems should be battery powered.

I would spend more money if the system would be Apple HomeKit enabled.

Any suggestions which system(s) could fit?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange, I'd recommend you take a tour of the site to learn what types of questions this site can help you with: https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour. This question is a "shop for me" question and is therefore not a question that this site can help answer. That said, try searching for "Thermostat with remote temperature sensor".

Answer (score 2):

There are radiator valves that are thermostatically controlled that need no batteries or outside input power. They do a pretty good job of controlling the temperature of a room.Try typing "Danfoss valves" in any search engine to investigate if valves like this would suit your needs. I should ask if your heating system is hot water or steam. The valves and controller are the same for both systems unless you have an old 1 pipe steam system, The temperature sensor usually mounts on the valve it is controlling. However they have some sensors that can be mounted a few feet away.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that by "thermostat" you mean "valve" (not having exactly the right word can throw off your search results a lot!)  The thermostat is the component that senses temperature and produces an on/off signal to maintain a target temperature.  The valve is the component that controls the water flow in the radiator.

If so, then what you want is:

1. a (ideally programmable) thermostat which can be mounted anywhere in the room)
2. a radiator valve that can be controlled by 1.

The simplest and cheapest solution is a "remote TRV" such as [this one](https://www.wolseley.co.uk/product/drayton-trv-4-remote-sensor-capillary-2-m/).  This will let you select an approximate temperature (often on a 0-5 scale) and then will turn the radiator on and off accordingly.  It's not programmable and has no electronics so no wifi or apps.

A more expensive system is one [like this](https://wiser.draytoncontrols.co.uk/smart-radiator-valves) where the valves are battery operated, communicate with a separate programmable thermostat, and can be controlled with an app.  Search for "wifi radiator valves" to find more.

Finally for even more money you can have HomeKit integration.  Search for "homekit smart radiator valve" and you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: I hate to say it but the asked question is from 4+ years ago.  Hopefully the OP would have found a solution by now.